# Consent Screen is prompted again even after permission is granted at app install time

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

We have a market place app with one service account and one web application client id listed in the project. We request a bunch of scopes when the app is installed, however  the user still hits a second permission screen the first time he runs the app

In the market place app api config page, we request the following scopes when we install the app:

URL../userinfo.email
URL../userinfo.profile
URL../drive 
URL../admin.directory.user
[Sorry cannot list entire url[

When user tries to signin to the our app, we make an oauth request with scope = "openid email" as per https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#scope-param

It seems the second permissions consent screen is due to some discrepancy in the requested scopes, but I am not able to trace it down.

Answer (score 1):

The scope for authentication must be `profile email`, not `openid email`. Also, check if you have performed [all the actions listed in this blog post](http://david-codes.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-provide-seamless-single-sign-on.html).

Comment: Thanks David, I tried profile email, just email, and even https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email. No luck. A just created user is still prompted for "Know who you are on Google" and "View your email address". I have ensured we have requested all the scopes including userinfo.email and userinfo.profile in the Market Place API Config page.

Comment: It would help if you post your authentication code, a screenshot of your Marketplace settings and your marketplace manifest.

Comment: Thanks David, we seem to have it working. I has to use scope as email+profile and I could only get this to work with our production app which is public. Thanks a lot, I basically followed your blog entry.